# my arduino code does not read any characters inputted from matlab

Tags: matlab, serialization, serial-port, arduino

I'm doing a serial communication from matlab to arduino. And my codes are written below. I just need suggestions or some advices because I'm not sure if my arduino is really reading the exact string that I'm inputting in matlab. However when I run the the matlab itself, fscan is reading and displaying the right set of characters. Please, are my codes right? I'm really confused.

====MATLAB CODE======

```
delete(instrfindall)

text=1;

s = serial('COM7', 'BaudRate', 38400);

fopen(s);

pause(0.1)

text=input('enter:  ','s');

fprintf(s, '%s\n', text);

pause(0.1);

fscanf(s)

pause(0.1)

delete(instrfindall)
```

====ARDUINO CODE=====

```
String inData; // Where to store string
char received; // Where to store the character read // Index into array; where to store the character


void setup(){
Serial.begin(38400);
}

void loop()
{   
while(Serial.available() > 0) // Do not execute if one less than the size of the array
   {
       char received = Serial.read(); // Read a character
       inData += received; 
       if(received == '\n');
     {
    Serial.print(inData);  
    inData="";
 }
   }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you never write '\n', as the input() matlab function remove it. So just add it at the end of `text` and everything will work. Also pay attention, as if `inData` grows bigger than a number like 100 char, you will probably run out of ram and have weird result.

Comment: @ lesto Thank you lesto for answering. Where '\n' are you pertaining? Is it if(received == '\n') part in  my arduino code? Yea, inData really grows bigger that's why I put  inData=""; part to clear out the data inside the buffer. Ok I will try your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Arduino waot for a \n from matlab witch never arrive. So you need to add newline on the arduino code

Comment: @ lesto Whenever I put '\n' after the text in fprintf(s, text\n,'sync'); I got error: Undefined function or variable 'n'.Error in serialcom1 (line 7)
fprintf(s, text\n,'sync'); Am I doing the right thing? :)

Comment: of couse, text is a variable NAME, you have to add the '\n' (is is a special letter witch means new line) at the end of the string.

you can alter the text value like this:
text= strcat(text,'1n')
OR
you can add a printf that print just this character:
fprintf(s, '\n','sync');

Comment: I just change the fprintf part with: fprintf(s, '%s\n', text,'sync'); is the code right? I think I got the right result here....enter: 09486744118

ans =

09486744118

Comment: seems so, just i can't understand why 'sync' is there, but i nevere used matlab... but if it is like c/c++, you can remove it. the result seem right, right?

Comment: @ lesto Thanks lesto for your advices. I deleted the 'sync' part but still arrived with the right results. Thanks!!!!! :))))